# Changing Spring Application Started Message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I used spring boot to do a sample service. It works fine when i run it using 
"java -jar DemoLibrary.war" command in commandline. I get the proper message that "Library Application Has Started".

I did like below in Appplication.java file;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    LogService.info(Application.class.getName(), "Library Application Has Started.");
}
   }
```

When i run it in a external tomcat, it starts fine and works also fine. But i dont see the same message as it doesnot use that main method anymore. I just see spring application started message.

Is there a way i can change that message and give as i want?

Comment: does a ``CommandLineRunner`` work when executing in an tomcat environment?

Comment: No it doesnot. As i have given path in log4j.xml like,  <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/LibraryDemo_log.log"/>. So i think all is logged in this file.

Comment: You should add an `ApplicationListener` and listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`s.  That should work regardless the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`onStartup`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.html#onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)), something like:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    LogService.info(Application.class.getName(), "Library Application Has Started.");
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
```

Comment: I added that in Application.java file. Now it does not start anymore. Just shows that message.

Comment: Sorry i dont know much in spring. I just see exmaples and follow to learn.

Comment: Now the message shows as the first line in logger. Then all the mappings are loaded and "Spring Application Started Message". Is there a way i can give the message after everything is loaded and ready?

Comment: fyi, i see this line after it has started; INFO  [2015-05-18 11:06:04] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] [localhost-startStop-1] - [Started application in 6.993 seconds (JVM running for 11.86)]

Comment: moving `super.onStartup(servletContext);` before `LogService.info(...` should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Add an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` typed class and register it as a `@Bean`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> startupLoggingListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>() {   
            public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
                    LogService.info(Application.class.getName(), "Library Application Has Started.");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Something like this should work in both situations without duplicating code (although the code isn't complex but still).

Comment: That is awesome. Didn't knew that. Thank you. I wish i can also select as answer, but sadly i can only accept one.